# How to sync times of two devices with Android NTP?

Tags: system, date-and-time, time-zones

We have 2 android devices running same application that users see their GUI. Time synchronization is curicial for us. To make them have same time we have the settings as below.

Use these commands in boot and after every 5 minutes but it seems after 8 9 hours of uptime two android devices have different times with respect to their seconds. ex:

busybox watch -n 1 date

```
DEVICE 1: (Android 6 Marshmallow) 2020-03-10 09:16:33
DEVICE 2: (Android 6 Marshmallow) 2020-03-10 09:16:38


settings put global ntp_server pool.ntp.org
settings put global auto_time 0
settings put global auto_time 1
```

After that we also tried below commands but not worked

```
settings put global ntp_polling_interval 10
settings put global ntp_pollinginterval 10
settings put global ntppollinginterval 10
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the devices rooted? AFAIK "fine adjusting" (i.e. to less than 30s) is only possible with rooted devices / system applications. Not sure if that still applies: Take e.g. a look at [Atomic Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.apps.atomic_clock_watch_accuracy_tool), which doesn't mention root as requirement in its description.

Comment: so there isnt any methods to force ntp sync time in android, like in linux ntpdate?

Comment: https://github.com/wlach/ntpclient-android what about this?

Comment: When I last checked, correcting the system time in intervals smaller than 30s (like fixing it by 2.3s) was not possible without root powers. No idea if that changed meanwhile, as I saw some apps not mentioning root requirements (or if their authors just missed to point that out).

Comment: FWIW Atomic clock is just a clock (it doesn't sync) and ntpclient-android doesn't work on newer versions of Android